# ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

who use ngx-toast service in http interceptor?

in 'app.module.ts'

```
 {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: HeadersInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
}
```

and in 'error.interceptor.ts' file

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private toastr: ToastService,
    ) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                tap(evt => {
                    if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        if (evt.body && evt.body.data && (evt.status === 201 || evt.status === 200)) {
                            return this.toastr.showSuccess(
                                {
                                    message: evt.body.message,
                                    title: 'OK',
                                    closeButton: true,
                                    enableHtml: true,
                                    progressBar: true
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    let errorMsg = '';
                    const errorTitle = 'Error';
                    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                        errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;

                        this.toastr.showError(
                            {
                                message: errorMsg,
                                title: 'Error',
                                closeButton: true,
                                enableHtml: true,
                                progressBar: true
                            });
                    } else {
                        let title = '';
                        let message = '';

                        title = `${errorTitle} ${error.status}`;
                        message = error.error.message;
                        this.toastr.showError(
                            {
                                message,
                                title,
                                closeButton: true,
                                enableHtml: true,
                                progressBar: true
                            });
                        errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
                    }
                    return throwError(errorMsg);
                })
            );
    }
}
```

and I wrote a custom toast service

when I use ToastService with httpInterceptor, I got this error:

> Blockquote
> ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS

Comment: Any change you injected ErrorInterceptor into your toaster service class as well?

Comment: Show us the `ToastService` code